# How to enable autocomplete messages on Facebook messenger using set of entities?

Tags: python-3.x, autocomplete, dialogflow-es, facebook-messenger-bot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a Facebook page, Python backend, PostgreSQL DB and Dialogflow agent.

A user communicates with my chat bot by sending a message to my FB page.
This messages is going through my Python backend straight to the Dialogflow agent for analysis (intents, entities etc.).

Dialogflow sends the interpreted text back to my Python backend which replies the user back on Facebook.

Please advise how can I enable autocomplete when user enters a message based on list of entities?

For example I am storing a list of entities (names) ["John", "Mike", "Steve" ....]

When user enters "J" I am presenting him with an autocomplete options: John, Jennifer ....

So the first question is if it's possible, and the second one is how to do this? 
I will appreciate any help or direction what to check.

Comment: I don’t think the Messenger API has any such autocomplete functionality to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook messenger does not support Autocomplete feature.

Check for all the available features [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages)